# Check if directory is a mount point?

Tags: ansible, mount

I need to check if a directory is a mount point before doing some other tasks.

I have been looking around the documentation and it only seems that you can create/destroy mount points but not just check if one exists. From the link below.

http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/mount_module.html

I am wondering if there is any way to check it exists with ansible, or will it have to be some other language called from ansible.

Answer (score 20):

I've tried with both `mount` and `stat` module. Both didn't met your requirements.

I've manage to work only using a OS command. I've tested on Redhat, Debian and SLES families.

```
vars:
    - myvolume: /backup

tasks:

   - command: mountpoint -q {{myvolume}}
     register: volume_stat
     failed_when: False
     changed_when: False

    - debug:
       msg: "This is a mountpoint!"
      when: volume_stat.rc == 0
```

The problem is, `mountpoint` command generates stderr if the path isn't a mount point so you have to use `ignore_errors`, witch is not a good solution.

**EDIT 1**: Is mentioned by @udondan, `failed_when` is a better approach then `ignore_errors` since it doesn't output errors.

It may be what you want if you need to stop the playbook if the path isn't a mount point.

I hope someone find a better solution than this.

**NOTE**: There is some platforms that doesn't have `mountpoint` command, as far as I know Darwin (Mac OSX) and SunOS (Oracle Solaris), if you need this to work on those systems, you'll need to find another workaround.

Comment: I believe to create a mountpoint the target actually needs to exist. But an existing path does not mean it is mounted.

Comment: Instead of `ignore_errors: true` you could use `failed_when: false`. It's a bit less ugly because it wouldn't show the error in the output. On the other hand it would skip _all_ errors. I don't know if the `mountpoint` command might not exists on some systems? That would be something you would want to fail on. :) But if this is the way you want to go, you can fiddle with the `failed_when` condition.

Comment: Oh, much better @udondan. Darwin family (MacOS) and SunOS doesn't have `mountpoint` command. If OP need to work on those platforms it's better to make a conditional test before.

Comment: I think `volume_stat.rc == 1` means the opposite. Should it be `volume_stat.rc == 0`? I.e. `echo $?` gives me 0 if mount point is mounted.

Comment: @YauhenYakimovich, it was a typo, thanks for noticing it.

Answer (score 5):

After a while of trying I came up with this.

```
vars:
- myvolume: /backup

tasks:
- debug: msg="The dir is a mount point"
  with_items: ansible_mounts
  when: item.mount == myvolume
```

I am not sure how this applies to all systems and/or if `ansible_mounts` contains all the mount points of the OS or just the ones created with ansible.

Comment: I've tested this fact, it shows all mount points. Worked on SLES, RedHat and Ubuntu/Debian. On  SunOS (Solaris 11,10) , Darwin (MacOSX El Capitan) and HPUX the variable wasn't present. I rather solutions that doesn't require modules like `shell` or `command` because you can't use `dry run mode`.

Answer (score 5):

You can check this using the `ansible_mounts` fact, without running an extra command, although it's somewhat convoluted.

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ mount_point }} is mounted"
  when: ansible_mounts | selectattr('mount', 'equalto', mount_point) | list | length > 0

- debug:
    msg: "{{ mount_point }} is not mounted"
  when: ansible_mounts | selectattr('mount', 'equalto', mount_point) | list | length == 0
```

where `mount_point` is the directory path to check.

Note that Ansible facts don't automatically get updated, so if you mount or unmount the directory during the play the results will be out of date unless you update them by re-running the setup module:

```
- name: Gather facts again to update mount points
  setup:
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Ansible "command" module's "stdout" to determine the mount status of a given directory, example code is pasted here:

```
- name: "check mount point {{ mount_dir }}"
  command: mountpoint {{ mount_dir }}
  register: mount_stat
  failed_when: False
  changed_when: False

- name: "debug"
  when: mount_stat.stdout == "{{ mount_dir }} is a mountpoint"
  debug:
    msg: "{{ mount_dir }} is a mountpoint"

- name: "debug"
  when: mount_stat.stdout == "{{ mount_dir }} is not a mountpoint"
  debug:
    msg: "{{ mount_dir }} is not a mountpoint"
```

Comment: You should write more detailed answer. Firstly you need to mention source of posted text since you basically just copy-pasted it from documentation. Secondly this code can be seen on site provided by question author, so I believe he did read it. If so, he probably didn't understand that text. In the end I think he'll appreciate some comment of yours.

Answer (score 2):

Having similar difficulties, but try something like this -

```
- name: testing for required mount points
  fail:
    msg: "{{ item }} must be a mount point"
  when: not item|is_mount  
  with_items: 
    - /path/to/test
```

Now if I can just figure out how to dependably get the *size* of the mount point, lol

BTW, worth looking at the default facts, like `{{ ansible_mounts }}`, though my /dev/shm isn't showing there - dunno why yet. *Caveat scriptor*, ymmv.